# How to send multiple Images from client to server through java sockets?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

**Updated**

I am trying to send multiple images from client to server.
Client has two threads

1. Thread 1 is taking screenshot
2. thread 2 is sending screenshot to server

this code is taking 2 screenshots. But only first screenshot is successfully saved on server. Please help me to send and save multiple images to server.

No Error, no exception.

Output:

thread1 is running...

thread2 is running...

thread1 is running...

thread2 is running...

**Client**

```
abstract class ScreenCapture implements Runnable{

 static BufferedImage screencapture;
 static ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
 static byte[] ImageInBytes;

   public static void main(String args[]) throws
       AWTException, IOException, InterruptedException {

  // Open your connection to a server, at port 1234
  final Socket ClientSocket = new Socket("localhost",1234);

  final DataOutputStream dos= new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());
  DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream() );
  baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

  try{
      //First thread that is Taking screenshot
      Thread TakeScreenShotthread = new Thread () 
      {
          public void run () {        

          // Capture Screen using BufferedImage Library
           try {
               screencapture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
               new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()) );
               System.out.println("thread1 is running...");

            } catch (HeadlessException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (AWTException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
    };

    //Thread 2 that is Sending Screenshot to server
    Thread sendingScreenShotThread =new Thread () {
          public void run () {
              //Sending Screen to Server
               try {
                      ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", baos);
                      ImageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                      dos.write(ImageInBytes);
                     // File Rif = new File(System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
                      //ImageIO.write(screencapture, "jpg", Rif);
                      System.out.println("thread2 is running...");

                } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }       
               finally{

                    try {
                        baos.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }          
          }
        };
        TakeScreenShotthread.start();
        TakeScreenShotthread.sleep(1000);
        sendingScreenShotThread.start();
        sendingScreenShotThread.sleep(1000);
        TakeScreenShotthread.run();
        sendingScreenShotThread.run();
  }finally
  {
       //Closing Clients
                in.close();
                baos.close();
                ClientSocket.close();
  }  
  }
 }
```

**Server**

```
    public class ServerConnection
    { 
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    { 
    ServerSocket serversock = new ServerSocket(1234);
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    BufferedReader BF_RecievingGUID;
    clientSocket = serversock.accept();
    InputStream in=clientSocket.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = null; 

   try{    
        boolean processing=true;
       while(processing)
      {
       try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path));

       while ((in.read(buffer)) >= 0) { 
             out.write(buffer);
       }
       System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
   } catch (Exception e) {
   }finally {
       processing=false;
        if (out != null) out.close();
     }
   }
  }
  finally{
        BF_RecievingGUID.close();
        out.close();
      clientSocket.close();
        serversock.close();

        }   
    }
  }
```

Comment: How are you determining where one image ends and a new one starts?  If you don't do this yourself, it is most likely the reader will read all data as part of the first image.  I would also check the library you are caling is not closing any of the streams.

Comment: How can we determine that one image ends and a new one starts? please help

Comment: Why are you starting a thread to handle a socket and then doing I/O in the very next statement? This cannot possibly work. Rethink.

Answer (score 0):

it only reads once because you break the while loop:

```
if(RecievedImage != null)
{
     ImageIO.write(RecievedImage, "jpg", RecievedImageFile);
     RecievedImage.flush();
     System.out.println("Image file written successfully");
}else{
     System.out.println("image is empty");
}break;  //you break here
```

I don't get why you do this:

```
new Thread(new ThreadHandler(clientSocket)).start();
```

Comment: 'this makes these threads wait for 1 sec - no, it does not.  While the Sleep() calls are inappropriate for purpose here, you should understand that Sleep() pauses the calling thread only, no matter what thread instance it is called on.

Comment: Just read on the matter thanks for the clarification, updated my answer.

Comment: Still an error in 
BufferedImage RecievedImage = ImageIO.read(clientSocket.getInputStream()); .without break

Comment: We can't really help without the error... add the error in your question